# Embed video in Profile field for directory

Tags: custom-fields, profile, directory

Working on a public directory. The listings include a link to a YouTube video. It is working fine with a custom field of the type link. We would like to embed the videos in the search results. I created a custom field for this. When I add the embed code in the back end I get.

> Network Error
>   Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

If I use a text area field with rich text editor and paste the code using the source view the video shows and can be played when you switch out of source but it will not save.

Using WordPress 4.9 & CiviCRM 4.7.27

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same steps on [wpmaster](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/) and i was able to add embeded video. Here is what i did:

1. Added 2 custom field of type Link and Note(RichTextEditor).
2. Added above 2 fields in a Profile search.
3. Updated custom field for individual

   - Added video link to link type custom field.
   - Added embed video code to Note type custom field.
     [image]
4. On [Profile search mode](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fprofile&gid=16&reset=1) i did a search on contact #3
   [image]

Can you check CiviCRM Log to see any error being recorded?